# Don't understand why Sidekiq tests are failing with Testing::inline! when others wont

Tags: rspec, rspec-rails, sidekiq, rspec-sidekiq

I am about to write tests for a Imaage Worker. I don't understand why some of the tests are failing when using `Sidekiq::Testing.inline!` when others with the same structure wont.

Can someone explain please

- why the first test fails WITH `Sidekiq::Testing.inline!`
- why the second test fails WITHOUT `Sidekiq::Testing.inline!`

```rb
class ProductImageJob
  include Sidekiq::Job

  sidekiq_options retry: 3

  def perform(product_id, enable_after_update = true)
    product = Product.unscoped.find(product_id)

    if product.generate_variants
      product.mark_visible! if enable_after_update
      logger.info "Images for product #{product_id} generated"
    else
      raise StandardError, "Product images for ID #{product_id} could not be generated"
    end

  end
end
```

```rb
# rails_helper.rb
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:each) do
    Sidekiq::Worker.clear_all
  end
end

# spec/jobs/product_image_job.rb
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe ProductImageJob do

  let(:product) { Fabricate :product }

  describe 'perform' do

    it 'should call generate_variants' do
      # Sidekiq::Testing.inline! # when UNcommented: FAILS

      expect_any_instance_of(Product).to receive(:generate_variants)

      ProductImageJob.perform_async(product.id)
    end

    it 'should receive mark_visible! if job done' do
      Sidekiq::Testing.inline! # when COMMENTED FAILS
      # allow_any_instance_of(Product).to receive(:generate_variants).and_return(true)
      expect_any_instance_of(Product).to receive(:mark_visible!)

      ProductImageJob.perform_async(product.id)
    end
  end

end
```

I also tried to mock the `generate_variants` as you can see, but that does not change it's behaviour.

**Both tests are generally doing the same thing, why is the one failing and the others not, and vice versa?**

Comment: Could you please share your entire spec file?

Comment: @SampatBadhe I've updated my answer and added the wrapping rspec code as well partially spec_helper content